# Disallow MATLAB to take focus automatically

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have the following problem: in my MATLAB code I use statements like

```
figure(1)
```

to change destination figure for some data. The problem is that after this MATLAB take system focus on the window with this figure.

When I run a big script in the background and try to do something else on my computer, MATLAB always takes focus and I can't do something normally.

Is there a way to disallow MATLAB to do this? I'm working in Linux Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R2018a, the figure property "WindowState" was introduced, see https://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2018/07/13/maximize-your-figures/

Using this, you can do

```
set(0, 'DefaultFigureWindowState', 'minimized');
```

before running the actual script, and this will cause all "standard plots" to not steal focus and be opened in minimized state.

There are functions that still steal focus. I did not investigate in detail, but I believe it's mainly automatic plotting functions such as psd, hist etc. without output arguments. If you call `plot` yourself you should be fine.

Comment: Why the downvote? A comment would be nice.

Answer (score 6):

["Smart"/Silent Figure](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8919-smartsilent-figure)  by Daniel Eaton.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by making the figure invisible (visible off) at creation, and only making it visible when you want to show it.

For example:

```
f = figure('Visible', 'off'); %create an invisible figure
plot(rand(1,15)); %plot some stuff to it.

saveas(f, 'test.png', 'png'); %write out the image as a png
close(f); %destroy the figure
```

Alternatively:
    set(f, 'Visible', 'on'); %display a previously invisible figure

Note, if you save the figure as a Matlab `.fig` file, it will also save the fact that it is invisible, which can be a bit confusing.

Comment: By the way, in Linux I just moved matlab screen to another workspace

Comment: Hah! Clever. Pity that wouldn't work for windows. It would be nice if we could generally revoke permission for specific programs to steal focus.

Comment: @Shaun314 thanks for spotting the typo

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, but based on the link to the smart figure, it looks like all you need to do to make your figure isn't stealing focus is this:

```
set(0, 'CurrentFigure', h);
```

And by the way, if you didn't know, the 0 is meaning "root"